# Count average for group in R

Tags: r

I have data frame that have date field. I need to create ggplot + geom_col that represent average amount by day for each hour (0-23)

I'm able to get total for every hour like this:

```
logs %>%
  mutate(Hour = format(as.POSIXct(Date), format = "%H")) %>%
  count(Hour) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Hour, y = n)) + geom_col()
```

I need to get average values instead of totals. I found many questions about how to calculate average based on field, like this [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group), but I need to get average value based on items count. Example:

- id,date
- 1,2023-05-19 04:49:40
- 2,2023-05-18 04:49:40
- 3,2023-05-18 04:49:40
- 4,2023-05-18 04:49:40

Here I have 4 items for 04 o'clock, so in the plot I must see 3(May 18) + 1(May 19)/2(total days) = 2 value in 04 column, and so on for each hour